# What's the meaning of "to dog his heels"

Tags: idioms, literature

I've come across *Elia's Peattie, The Shape of Fear*  but I can't figure out the meaning of the following sentence. Is it an idiom or phrase?

> "Purity seemed **to dog his heels**, no matter how violently he
>   attempted to escape from her. "

Comment: Imagine a dog following closely at your heels mo matter where you go and which way you turn.

Comment: In other words to "follow". Many thanks.

Comment: To anybody who thinks this should be answered by a dictionary: have you tried?

Comment: @DCShannon I just did a Google search for "dog definition" and found: ["follow (someone or their movements) closely and persistently."](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=dog+definition&oq=dog+definition&gs_l=hp.3..0l5j0i22i30l5.326.1500.0.1675.14.9.0.0.0.0.288.913.0j3j2.5.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..9.5.909.2zHr2dpw3_0)

Comment: @DCShannon: Well, looking up the verb form of "dog" mostly answers this, yes. Still, it's not the most obvious and a trivial search doesn't really do a good job.

Comment: @pyobum It never even occurred to me to look up 'dog' by itself. I couldn't find anything on "dog his heels". Still, even if you looked up dog and found that definition, it's worth asking "is it an idiom or a phrase"? Furthermore, how does purity follow someone? I think this deserves an explanation. as it's a bit idiomatic.

Comment: "To dog" and "to dog ___'s heels" are not identical. The former could be found in a dictionary definition, but the latter probably could not, especially considering the unappreciated directing behavior that TRomano explains.  "Purity seemed to follow him, no matter how violently he attempted to escape from her" doesn't suitably convey the illustration of "to dog ___'s heels"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some dogs (sheep herders) nip at the heels of the sheep, to direct them.

For example:
http://pets.thenest.com/keep-shelties-nipping-backs-legs-6151.html

So the implication is not merely of following, but of changing the behavior of the one followed.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it does not mean just *to follow*, but to *follow so closely as to be a nuisance, since the one doing the dogging is following you so closely and constantly and as if to bite you on the heels that you want to kick the SOB*.